find the maximum of $2x+y$
$3x^{2}+3xy+y^{2} = 3$
$x,y$ are real numbers.  Find the maximum of $2x+y$.
I actually have no idea about this; usually I will use Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, but obviously it doesn't work.
I've asked my classmate to teach me, but I don't know why he let $2x+y$ be $k$.
It would be more helpful if you can provide not just one method;
thanks!
Summary:
1.manipulate $3x^{2}+3xy+y^{2} = 3$ into
a form like $(2x+y)^2 + \frac{y^2}{3} = 4$.
Since $\frac{y^2}{3} \ge 0$,then
$(2x+y)^2 \le 4$.
Hence, $|2x+y|\le 2$.
Then by eliminating the absolute value the maximum of $2x+y$ is 2.
2.by using discriminant $\Delta \ge 0$ since the solution always exists,and let $2x+y$ be $k$ will be easier to operate,and $k$ is a clearer notaion of the objective.
3.by using calculus,this part is hard for me and I will review this again tomorrow.

Hint: $$3x^2+3xy+y^2={3\over 4}(2x+y)^2+{1\over 4}y^2$$

actually the answer is 2...I see, method in comment  above

$4x^2+4xy+\frac43y^2=4\implies (2x+y)^2+\frac13y^2=4\implies 2x+y\le2$

"but I don't know why he let 2x+y be k "  Why not?  You want to find the maximum value of $2x+y$ so it'd be useful to be put $3x^2 + 3xy + y^3 =3$ in terms of $(2x+y)$ and it might be easier to use that as a single variable.

yeah but sometimes it's not easy to think of this way,especially we often deal with one variable at our school,this is just not very common

that's right,and this makes finding $(2x+y)^2$ easier(I think)

The first solution is in the comment of @RyszardSzwarc.
Here is a second solution from the idea of your classmate: let $k = 2x +y$. From this, we have:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{k^2}{3} = \frac{(2x+y)^2 }{3x^2 + 3xy +y^2} &\iff k^2x^2+k^2 xy+ \frac{k^2}{3}y^2=4x^2+4xy+y^2\\
&\iff  (k^2 -4)x^2+(k^2 -4)xy +\left( \frac{k^2}{3}-1 \right) = 0 \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
The quadratic equation $(1)$ of $x$ has solution if and only if the discriminant  $\Delta $ is positive, that is
$$\begin{align}\Delta =(k^2-4)^2-4(k^2 -4)\left( \frac{k^2}{3}-1 \right) \ge 0 &\iff -\frac{1}{3}(k^2 -4)k^2 \ge 0\\
&\iff \color{red}{-2\le k\le 2}
\end{align}$$
I let you seek the value $(x,y)$ such that $2x+y$ reaches its maximum of $2$ to finish the problem.

I understood,but why the discriminant can equal 0? I think it should be just more than 0

@Onebytheside No, the quadratic equation has solution if and only if the discriminant is positive (in this case, the equation has two distinct solutions) or equal to zero (in this case, the equation has 1 solution). The latter case is also the scenario where the maximum of $2$ is reached.

Addendum added to respond to the comment questions of Onebytheside.

Alternative approach:
Use Calculus.
$$3x^{2}+3xy+y^{2} = 3. \tag1 $$
(1) above can be interpreted as a quadratic equation in $~y,~$ which will allow you to express $~y~$ as a function of $~x.~$  That is, $~y = f(x).~$
Once you have the expression $~y = f(x),~$ you can then construct the function $~g(x) = 2x + y = 2x + f(x).$
Then, you can identify the allowable domain for the variable $~x,~$ and then interrogate the behavior of the function $~g(x)~$ by examining its derivative.

$$y^2(1) + y(3x) + (3x^2 - 3) = 0 \implies $$
$$y = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~-3x \pm \sqrt{ ~9x^2 - 4(3x^2 - 3) ~} ~\right]$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~-3x \pm \sqrt{ ~12 - 3x^2 ~} ~\right].$$
So, there are two distinct functions $~y = f(x)~$ that will each satisfy the equation in (1) above.  These functions are
$$y = f_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~-3x + \sqrt{ ~12 - 3x^2 ~} ~\right]. \tag{2.1} $$
$$y = f_2(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~-3x - \sqrt{ ~12 - 3x^2 ~} ~\right]. \tag{2.2} $$
Furthermore, the functions expressed in (2.1) and (2.2) above both have the same allowable domain for the variable $~x.~$
That is, in both (2.1) and (2.2), the expression $~12 - 3x^2~$ is not allowed to be negative.
Therefore,
$$3x^2 \leq 12 \implies x^2 \leq 4 \implies 
-2 \leq x \leq 2. \tag3 $$
Now, using (2.1) and (2.2) above, you can construct the corresponding equations $~g(x) = 2x + f(x):$
$$g_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~x + \sqrt{ ~12 - 3x^2 ~} ~\right]. \tag{4.1} $$
$$g_2(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~x - \sqrt{ ~12 - 3x^2 ~} ~\right]. \tag{4.2} $$
You are trying to find the maximum value of either $~g_1(x)~$ or $~g_2(x).$  Clearly, for any value of the variable $~x,~$ in the allowable domain, the function $~g_1(x)~$ will never be less than the value of the function $~g_2(x).$
Therefore, the function $~g_2(x)~$ may be dropped from consideration, and you can focus exclusively on maximizing the function
$$g_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~x + \sqrt{ ~12 - 3x^2 ~} ~\right] ~: ~- 2 \leq x \leq 2.  \tag5 $$

From (5) above,
$$g_1'(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left\{ ~1 + \left[ ~\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{ ~12 - 3x^2 ~}} \times (-6x) ~\right] ~\right\}. \tag6 $$
At this point, you are looking for the (algebraically) simplest way of completing the problem.  In this situation, a good starting point is to identify each value of $~x~$ such that $~-2 \leq x \leq 2,~$ and such that $~g_1'(x) = 0.~$
For each such value of $~x,~$ you can manually compute $~g_1(x).$
Further, you can also manually compute $~g_1(x)~$ at the endpoints $~x = -2,~$ and $~x = +2.$
Depending on what you find, the above approach may or may not be sufficient to conquer the problem.

$$g_1'(x) = 0 \implies ~1 - \frac{3x}{\sqrt{ ~12 - 3x^2 ~}} = 0 \implies $$
$$ \sqrt{12 - 3x^2} = 3x \implies $$

$3x \geq 0.$

$(12 - 3x^2) = 9x^2 \implies x^2 = 1.$


So, in the range $~-2 \leq x \leq 2,~$ the sole value of $~x~$ such that $~g_1'(x) = 0~$ is at $~x = 1.$
Then:

$\displaystyle g_1(1) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~1 + \sqrt{ ~12 - 3 ~} ~\right] = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~1 + 3 ~\right] = 2.$

$\displaystyle g_1(-2) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~2 + \sqrt{ ~0 ~} ~\right] = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~2 ~\right] = 1.$

$\displaystyle g_1(2) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~-2 + \sqrt{ ~0 ~} ~\right] = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~2 ~\right] = -1.$



Because there was only one value of $~x,~$ in the allowable domain, such that $~g_1'(x) = 0,~$ the analysis is complete.  That is, there is no need to algebraically determine the behavior of $~g_1'(x)~$ in the interval $~-2 \leq x \leq 2,~$ and so there is no need to interrogate $~g_1''(x)~$ [i.e. the 2nd derivative of $~g_1(x)$].
So, since the sole value of $~x~$ in the domain $~-2 \leq x \leq 2~$  such that $~g_1'(x) = 0~$ is where $~x = 1,~$ and since $~g_1(1)~$ is greater than both $~g_1(-2)~$ and $~g_1(2),~$ you must have that in the interval $~-2 \leq x \leq 2,~$ that $~g_1(x)~$ achieves its maximum value at $~x = 1.~$
That is, it has been analytically established that $~g_1(x)~$ is increasing on the interval $~-2 < x < 1,~$ and decreasing on the interval $~1 < x < 2.$
Therefore, the maximum value of $~(2x + y)~$ equals the maximum value of $~g_1(x)~$ in the interval $~-2 \leq x \leq 2,~$ and this value is
$$g_1(1) = 2.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

$~y^2(1)+y(3x)+(3x^2−3)=0. ~$ What does this mean?

This represents a re-expression of the equation in (1) above into the form of a 2nd degree polynomial equation (i.e. quadratic equation) in terms of the variable $~y.~$  That is, it represents the equation:
$$[ ~y^2 \times 1 ~] + [ ~y \times 3x ~] + [ ~(3 \times x^2) - 3 ~] = 0.$$
The point is that since the above equation has the form
$$Ay^2 + By + C = 0,$$
where
$$A = 1, ~B = 3x, ~C = [ ~(3 \times x^2) - 3 ~], $$
you can apply the formula for solving quadratic equations:
$$y = \frac{1}{2A} ~\left[ ~-B \pm \sqrt{ ~B^2 - 4AC ~} ~\right].$$

When do I need to interrogate 2nd derivative, and what can it do?

The easiest way of answering this question is to use the specific math problem in the posted question as an illustrative example.  In my answer, consider the situation at the exact point that equation (5) is reached.
That is, at equation (5), you have an exact specification for $~y = g_1(x),~$ and an interval $~-2 \leq x \leq 2.~$ Then, you are trying to find the specific value of $~x~$ that maximizes the value of $~g_1(x)~$ in this interval.
Before focusing on the 2nd derivative, focus on the first derivative, $~g_1'(x)~$ which is expressed in (6) above.  The subsequent analysis in my posted answer indicates that there is exactly one value of $~x_0~$ in the interval $~-2 \leq x_0 \leq 2~$ such that $~g_1'(x_0) = 0.~$
This value is $~x_0 = 1.~$
At this point, without doing anything else, you immediately know that one of the two mutually exclusive possibilities below, must be true:

$g_1(x)~$ attains a maximum value at $~x_0=1,~$ and so this maximum value is $~g_1(1).~$ 
In order for this to be true, you must have that the endpoint values, $~g_1(-2)~$ and $~g_1(2)~$ are both less than $~g_1(1).$ 
If this proves to be the case, then the problem is solved, since the answer will be $~g_1(1).$

$g_1(x)~$ attains a minimum value at $~x_0=1,~$ and so this minimum value is $~g_1(1).~$
In order for this to be true, you must have that the endpoint values, $~g_1(-2)~$ and $~g_1(2)~$ are both greater than $~g_1(1).$ 
If this proves to be the case, then the problem is solved, since the answer will be either $~g_1(-2),~$ or $~g_1(2).$


Before proceeding further, you have to understand why one of the two bullet points above must be correct.  $~g_1(x)~$ is a continuous function.  In the interval $~-2 \leq x \leq 2,~$ any time that $~g_1(x)~$ changes direction, there must be a specific value $~x_0~$ in this interval such that $~g_1'(x_0) = 0.~$
Here, I am using the phrase change direction to indicate that $~g_1(x)~$ either went from strictly increasing to strictly decreasing, or went from strictly decreasing to strictly increasing.
The idea is that if $~g_1(x)~$ went from strictly increasing to strictly decreasing, this means that the first derivative, $~g_1'(x)~$ went from positive to negative.  Since $~g_1'(x)~$ is itself a continuous function, this means that at some point $~g_1'(x)~$ crossed the $~x$-axis, so that $~g_1'(x) = 0,~$ at some point.
Similarly, if $~g_1(x)~$ went from strictly decreasing to strictly increasing, this means that the first derivative, $~g_1'(x)~$ went from negative to positive.  Since $~g_1'(x)~$ is itself a continuous function, this again means that at some point $~g_1'(x)~$ crossed the $~x$-axis, so that $~g_1'(x) = 0,~$ at some point.
Therefore, since $~g_1'(x)~$ is itself a continuous function, and since there is exactly one value of $~x_0~$ in the interval $~-2 \leq x_0 \leq 2,~$ such that $~g_1'(x_0) = 0,~$ and since $~x_0 \neq -2,~$ and $~x_0 \neq 2,~$ one of the two mutually exclusive situations below must be correct:

$g_1'(x)~$ is negative in the interval $~-2 \leq x < x_0,~$ 
and $g_1'(x)~$ is positive in the interval $~x_0 < x \leq 2.$ 
This implies that $~g_1(x)~$ is decreasing in the interval $~-2 \leq x < x_0~$ and increasing in the interval $~x_0 < x \leq 2.$ 
This implies that $~g_1(x)~$ attains a minimum value at $x = x_0.$

$g_1'(x)~$ is positive in the interval $~-2 \leq x < x_0,~$ 
and $g_1'(x)~$ is negative in the interval $~x_0 < x \leq 2.$ 
This implies that $~g_1(x)~$ is increasing in the interval $~-2 \leq x < x_0~$ and decreasing in the interval $~x_0 < x \leq 2.$ 
This implies that $~g_1(x)~$ attains a maximum value at $x = x_0.$


So, the entire problem is reduced to determining which of the two bullet points directly above is correct.
Now, consider the situation in my posted analysis, at the exact point where the following conclusion is reached:

So, in the range $~-2 \leq x \leq 2,~$ the sole value of $~x~$ such that $~g_1'(x) = 0~$ is at $~x = 1.$

At this point, there has been no interrogation of either the second derivative, $~g_1''(x),~$ or the value $~g_1(x_0),~$ or the endpoint values $~g_1(-2), ~g_1(2).~$
So, at this point, the problem solver has two alternative methods of completing the problem.
The first method is to use the second derivative, $~g_1''(x),~$ to analyze the behavior of the first derivative, $~g_1'(x),~$ at the exact value $~x = x_0.$
If $~g_1''(x_0)~$ is positive, this implies that $~g_1'(x)~$ is increasing at $~x = x_0.~$  This implies that $~g_1'(x)~$ is negative for $~-2 \leq x < x_0~$ and $~g_1'(x)~$ is positive for $~x_0 < x \leq 2.$  This implies that the first bullet point directly above is correct.
If $~g_1''(x_0)~$ is negative, this implies that $~g_1'(x)~$ is decreasing at $~x = x_0.~$  This implies that $~g_1'(x)~$ is positive for $~-2 \leq x < x_0~$ and $~g_1'(x)~$ is negative for $~x_0 < x \leq 2.$  This implies that the second bullet point directly above is correct.
If instead, $~g_1''(x_0) = 0,~$ then the problem can not be completed merely by interrogating the second derivative.
The only drawback to the approach of evaluating $~g_1''(x_0)~$ is that sometimes, as in the present problem, the expression for the second derivative will be messy, and attempting to determine the value of $~g_1''(x_0)~$ will itself be difficult.
In such an event, fortunately, there is an alternative method of completing the problem.  This is the alternative that I used.
Since you know that $~g_1(x)~$ changed direction exactly once in the interval $~-2 \leq x \leq 2,~$ it is sufficient to manually compute $~g_1(x_0),~$ and to also manually compute the specific values at the end points, $~g_1(-2),~$ and $~g_1(2).~$
As discussed, you know that these end point values will either both be greater than $~g_1(x_0),~$ or both be less than $~g_1(x_0).$  By manually computing the three values, $~g_1(x_0), ~g_1(-2),~$ and $~g_1(2),~$ you are then able to determine whether the maximum value of $~g_1(x)~$ is attained at $~x = -2, ~x = x_0, ~$ or $~x = 2.$

$y^2(1) + y(3x) + (3x^2 - 3) = 0$ what does this mean?

When do I need to interrogate 2nd derivative, and what can it do?

@Onebytheside For my response to both of your comment questions, see the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

$3x^{2}+3xy+y^{2} = 3\implies 4x^2+4xy+\frac43y^2=4\implies (2x+y)^2+\frac13y^2=4$.
Since $\frac13y^2\ge0$, it follows that $(2x+y)^2\le4$, i.e., $\lvert 2x+y\rvert\le2$.
Indeed, when $y=0,  x=\pm1$, and $2x+y=\pm2$, so the maximum value of $2x+y$ obtained is $2$.

I seemed to gave you the negative feedback,hope that was not real.

But how did you let $3x^2 + 3xy + y^2 = 3$ be $4x^2 + 4xy + \frac{4y^2}{3} = 4$?

I multiplied both sides of the equation by $\frac43$; that made completing the square easier

By the same logic,since $2x+y \ge 0$,then $\frac{y^2}{3} \le 4$.Then,find the maximum of $\frac{y^2}{3}$.  Can you still think of this way to find the maximum,and how will you do to lead you to the same method without $2x+y$?

$(2x+y)^{\color{red}2}\ge0$, so the maximum of $y^2$ is  $12$, but I thought you wanted the maximum of $2x+y$, which occurs when $y=0$

Well I mean change this into a new question to find the maximum of $\frac{y^2}{3}$,but $2x+y$ is not mentioned.Then can you still think of this method to solve the problem,and how?

As I indicated, the answer of the maximum of $\frac{y^2}3$ is $4$, but that belongs as a separate question
